# C- Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to build a a binary search tree. But I am not getting the correct output when performing the different traversals.

```
typedef struct binary_search_tree{
    struct binary_search_tree *lchild;
    int data;
    struct binary_search_tree *rchild;
}bst_t;

#define ALLOCATE (bst_t*)malloc(sizeof(bst_t))
```

Here is the insert function:

```
void insert(bst_t *ptr,int data){
    if( ptr->data < data){
        if ( ptr->lchild == NULL ){
            ptr->lchild = ALLOCATE;
            ptr->lchild->data = data;
            return;
        }else
            insert(ptr->lchild,data);
    }else{
        if ( ptr->rchild == NULL ){
            ptr->rchild = ALLOCATE;
            ptr->rchild->data = data;
            return;
        }else
            insert(ptr->rchild,data);
    }
}
```

Is this function correct?
I am sending the address of root while calling that function.

Comment: You have overlooked that `malloc` does not initialise the memory. So the pointers in the new node are not `NULL` but indeterminate.

Comment: I could not follow you. Will you please explain?

Comment: After `ptr->lchild->data = data;` you have missed out `ptr->lchild->lchild = NULL; ptr->lchild->rchild = NULL;` and similar in the other branch.

Comment: Or use `calloc`, but you didn't.

Comment: I did! But same thing.. I think as the structure is declared in static main memory so it is having initial values as `NULL`

Comment: No, the structure memory is dynamically obtained except possibly the root node.

Comment: [Here is the code.. Please tell me what else in needed?](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwdBHI1607sZek1LS19qMTJ3NVE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That code clearly shows the lines you have omitted: `ptr->lchild->lchild = ptr->lchild->rchild = NULL;` and similar in the other branch.

Comment: I have added them after you have told.

Comment: I copy pasted, compiled and ran the code you linked. It crashed.

Comment: [But it is running well. gcc 5.3.1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwdBHI1607sZNWItWVpvYU9vMW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: *"But I am not getting the correct output"* and *"But it is running well"* are contradictory, and vague. The only thing wrong with the code you posted is that you didn't properly initialize the structure after allocating it. Failure to properly initialize the structure leads to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797630/3386109), which means that anything can happen (including sort of working).

Comment: I have said  "But it is running well" after Weather Vane said that it crashed on his machine. Code is running .. But the correct output is not being produced.

Comment: @ParnabSanyal Ok, but that's the kind of symptom that can be caused by *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Okay I am trying to solve it.Thanks

Comment: When programming a data structure such as tree, always start with the empty case. Does your function work with an empty tree? Don't think so. One might say that the empty case is handled elsewhere, or that the trees are never empty, but this always leads to a trouble one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `ALLOCATE` macro. It doesn't do nearly enough to properly allocate and initialize a new node. I suggest creating a `newNode` function that allocates memory for the node, and then initializes all of the members of the structure, like this

```
bst_t *newNode(int data)
{
    // allocation and error checking
    bst_t *node = malloc(sizeof(bst_t));
    if ( node == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    // initialize the members of the structure
    node->lchild = NULL;
    node->data = data;
    node->rchild = NULL;

    return node;
}
```

Then the `insert` function can be simplified to this

```
void insert(bst_t *ptr,int data)
{
    if( ptr->data < data){
        if ( ptr->lchild == NULL )
            ptr->lchild = newNode(data);
        else
            insert(ptr->lchild,data);
    }else{
        if ( ptr->rchild == NULL )
            ptr->rchild = newNode(data);
        else
            insert(ptr->rchild,data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, here is the code.. I think  I have done what you have instructed but alas ! still not working.. thanks for your time though. If you find anything please tell me. [Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwdBHI1607sZMkFUdTF3NjlyNEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ParnabSanyal If you have other problems in the code, then you'll need to start a new question. In that question, be sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And also provide sample input, as well as expected and actual output.

Comment: Well! I have used the same ALLOCATE macro to my other binary-tree program. It is working fine and producing correct output. So, I think macro is not the problem here. Okay I will post this in a new thread.