# C pointer always contains its own memory address?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

Why does the pointer p always point to its own memory address as an integer in the following example. I can't see where it is initialized and would guess that it would be a garbage value. Can someone show me why it is not a garbage value. By the way I am compiling this in gcc with -std set to c99.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int *p; int a = 4;
    p = &a;
    *p++;
    printf("%d %u\n", *p, p);
}
```

Comment: Your code contains undefined behavior. Trying to explain the output of the program is a pointless exercise. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797630/3386109), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328) for more information. You can however, use a debugger to step through the assembly code.

Comment: thank you. I would accept your answer if I could. My question was really about why the undefined behavior seemed deterministic, but I'm sure the assembly code will help.

Comment: Can you clarify? You can't see were it's initialised? What about "p = &a;"?

Comment: @Steve Note that in C, `p = &a;` is _assignment_.  `int a = 4;` is _initialization_.  `p` is not _initialized_.

Comment: @chuck: I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem (as the other answers point out) is with `*p++;`. What that says to do is dereference p then increment the address in p.

From what you are seeing, we can assume `p` comes directly after `a` in memory

```
_________________________________________
|something |  a  |  p  | something else |
-----------------------------------------
```

So what ends up happening is `p` points to `a`, then is incremented so it points to itself (or more specifically: `p` stores the address that `p` is at).

Comment: Ohhhhh. Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Nit: `*p++` evaluates to the value stored at the current value of `p`, *then* increments `p`. So `*p++` should evaluate to `4`.

Comment: @JohnBode Very true. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to print a pointer value with %p, and your code has undefined behavior. You move the pointer one place after `a` and dereference it.

Your code doesn't illustrate the point you (it seems) wanted, the following will:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int *p; int a = 4;
    p = &a;
    printf("%d %p %p\n", *p, p, &p);
}
```

It produces something like:

```
4 0x7fff5c17da44 0x7fff5c17da48
```

`p` points to `a` then `*p` is the value of `a`. The value of `p` is `0x7fff5c17da44` which is the adresse of `a` and the address of `p` (`&p`) is `0x7fff5c17da48`.

Comment: could you try inserting the line *p++; after the line p=&a.  I used %u to illustrate the fact that the memory addresses are the same, but you'll see that this causes the output to change. After incrementing the pointer, the pointer points to a memory address, which contains an integer representation of itself. My question is why that integer representation is in memory there, when it doesn't appear to ever have been assigned.

Comment: I told you that it will produce an "undefined behavior": pointing just after an existing variable is authorized, but reading the value here is "undefined behavior".

Comment: No you didn't illustrate that the addresses are the same.